# Open a new tab and download a PDF at the sametime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

On clicking a PDF download link, I'd like the **pdf to be displayed in that same tab and in a second tab the page /case-studies to load**.

Is this possible?

Currently I've got:

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/155045/file-847580737-pdf/Stepping_into_a_new_age_of_marketing_with_CRM_FINAL_APPROVED.pdf" id="pdflink" target="_blank" download=""><strong>Click here to download your eBook</strong></a></h2>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
document.getElementById("pdflink").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "https://www.workbooks.com/case-studies";
    };
// ]]></script>
```

However this opens the redirect in a second tab but as the main window confusing the visitor (as if on IE or FF) they don't release the PDF has opened in the first tab.

Any advice?

Answer (score 11):

You should do it this way (during the onClick event):

```
window.open("https://www.workbooks.com/case-studies",'_blank');
```

Comment: @OP - add it before the location.href tho - otherwise you'll redirect before the new target is set ;)

Comment: Thanks please confirm what you mean @SidneyLiebrand